# Print floowing out in single row in java

Tags: java

How to print the following output with only one for-loop in java?

```
1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29.....till < 1000
```

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i += 4) System.out.print((i == 1 ? "" : ", ") + i);`

Comment: Do your own homework.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the code like this

```
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i += 4) {
    if (i == 997)
        System.out.print(i);
    else
        System.out.print(i + ", ");
}
```

But the next code will be faster:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 997; i += 4) {
    System.out.print(i + ", ");
}

System.out.print(997);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=1;i<1000;i+=4)
    System.out.println(i);
```